# How write different implementation of Spring3 Validator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a validator in Spring 3

```
Class X implements Validator{
   public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {

//Implementation 1
}
}

Class Y implements Validator{
   public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {

//Implementation 2
}
}
```

Now I want to validate my model on the basis of some situtation(may be Request Mapping1) by using Implementation 1 and in some other case(RequestMapping 2) I want to use Implementation 2.

How can I acheive this in Spring 3

This is binder

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        if (binder.getTarget() instanceof X) {
            binder.setValidator(new X());
        } 
    }

@RequestMapping("/Implementation1.html)
public String one(@Valid X x){
return "pg1";//I want 1st implementation of validator
}

@RequestMapping("/Implementation2.html)
public String one(@Valid X x){
return "pg2"; //I want 2nd implementation of validator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a configuration of spring mvc, that validates the beans using @Valid annotation. You can look there for help. https://github.com/andonescu/springmvc-freemarker/tree/spring-3.2v

** If you are configuring Spring MVC with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` then it will automatically configure a JSR 303 validator

- First of all, in my opinion, the object that you want to validate
  doesn't need to implement Validator interface.  Those classes should
  only, in the simplest case, implement **Serializable**.
- then, you can annotate fields from that class you want to validate -
  with constraints - annotations used by jsr 303 [example
  here](https://github.com/andonescu/springmvc-freemarker/blob/spring-3.2v/src/main/java/ro/andonescu/demos/springmvcfreemarker/webforms/RegistrationForm.java)
- third, when you use the class in controller, after the class was added as parameter in method, should be  `BindingResult bindingResult` , and you can use that binding result to find out if the that object has errors or not , [example here](https://github.com/andonescu/springmvc-freemarker/blob/spring-3.2v/src/main/java/ro/andonescu/demos/springmvcfreemarker/controllers/RegistrationController.java)

  @RequestMapping("/Implementation1.html)
         public String one(@Valid X x, BindingResult bindingResult){
        return "pg1";//I want 1st implementation of validator
  }

Comment: @lonut. You just explained how to write validator with spring3. My question was how to write multiple validator for same model attribute?

Comment: Then, just implement the org.springframework.validation.Validator interface in 2 different ways and when a request comes, you manually call what validation you want